# Javascript using regular expression to get date in middle of object

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this object `"FILTER_DATE":"LAST_MONTH", "FROM_DATE":"2/9/2020", "TO_DATE":"3/9/2020"` and need to extract the FROM_DATE value `2/9/2020`. I am trying to use replace, to replace everything before and after the from date with an empty string, but I'm not sure how to get both sides of the value. 
at the moment I can remove everything up until the date value with this... `/.*FROM_DATE":"/` but how can I now remove the final part of the object?

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean an Object or a String?

Comment: `var x = JSON.parse("{" + your_string + "}").FROM_DATE` is one way to get that and the other values, begs the question of your input is a json string in the first place?

Comment: apologies, it is a string in this case/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to make it with replace, just use:

```js
const input = '"FILTER_DATE":"LAST_MONTH", "FROM_DATE":"2/9/2020", "TO_DATE":"3/9/2020"';
const date = input.replace(/^.*"FROM_DATE":"([\d/]+)".*$/, '$1');
```

Now you can use `date` with just the date in it...

Comment: Thanks, this is the closest I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

In a second time you could remove `/",.*/`, but this seems too much heuristic to me.

You'd better just catch the first capturing group from the following regex:

```
/FROM_DATE":"([0-9][0-9]?\/[0-9][0-9]?\/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9])"/
```

```js
let str = '"FILTER_DATE":"LAST_MONTH", "FROM_DATE":"2/9/2020", "TO_DATE":"3/9/2020"';
let pattern = /FROM_DATE":"([0-9][0-9]?\/[0-9][0-9]?\/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9])"/
alert(str.match(pattern)[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your sample string looks *very much* like JSON. So much so in fact that you could just wrap it in braces, parse it as and object, and get the value of the FROM_DATE.

EG:

```js
function almostJsonStringToObject(str) {
  return JSON.parse('{' + str + '}');
}
var str = '"FILTER_DATE":"LAST_MONTH", "FROM_DATE":"2/9/2020", "TO_DATE":"3/9/2020"';
var obj = almostJsonStringToObject(str);
var fromdate = obj.FROM_DATE;
console.log(fromdate);
```